# A question about a circuit simulation using LM331 in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, lm331

I'm trying to convert 0..10V analog voltage to frequency by using an [LM331](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm331.pdf). 
Since LM331 works at 5V supply, I can scale 0..10V to 0..5V and feed it as the voltage input to the LM331.

I came across [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ059.png) circuit and this [forum](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/model-of-lm331-for-ltspice.121764/).
I followed the instructions to use LM331 in LTspice and simulated the circuit below:[image]

But I'm getting 5V constant output when I use 5V supply. LM331 should work with 5V supply. But in simulation with 5V it doesn't work. It works when I use 10V supply.

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain me how this circuit works? I mean C1 and R1 sets the frequency but thats all I know. What else sets what here? How can I set the duty cycle to around 50%? How can I modify this circuit so I can run the simulation for 5V supply?

Comment: The function of the chip is described in detail in section 8.1.1 of the data sheet.

Comment: Side note: if `ncl` and `nct` are just the chip's pins, *not* the node's labels, then those `.ic` conditions are useless. If the actual labels are `1` and `5`, then you may wish to change the directive to `.ic v(1)=0 v(5)=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the link to the forum you've posted I see that the initial schematic uses LTspice comparators (instead of the simpler `[Digital]/Schmitt`) and a bunch of other logic gates. There is also a comment in there saying:

> For  A1, A2, A3, set value Vhigh = Vs

Given that the supply in that example is 10 V my guess is that the `.SUBCKT` you're using needs adjusting those values (e.g. set `vhigh=5`). Maybe it's not set as a parameter, maybe it's not visible, maybe it's not even the case, but if you can provide a link for the exact subcircuit, or hierarchical schematic that you're using, it will be easier to tell if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From page 4, 7.1 Absolute Maximum Ratings table in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm331.pdf), the range of input voltage is -0.2V to +Vs.

Comment: Yes so I can use it with 12V supply as well then since Vs is max 40V. But on the on the other hand, on the first page it says "Operates on Single 5-V Supply" But it doesnt work at 5V supply in simulation.

Comment: While Vs at 5V, did u ensure that your input does not cross 5V?

Comment: Yes sure, I tried 1V 0.1V 2V and 4V for inputs and in all cases output was 5V. Do you think this circuit is correct? I also want more 50% like duty cycles.

Comment: The LM331 works by putting out fixed-width pulses and there is nothing you can do to change this. You can, however, follow the 331 with a divide by 2 circuit, using something like a 74HC74. This will give you a square wave at half the frequency.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Do you think the circuit in my simulation is correct? What is that poti for? And are the values of components dependent on supply voltage?

Comment: @user16307 - Your C2/R4 will produce a maximum output frequency of about 6 Hz, so it's possible that your simulation timebase is not long enough. And the pot is there to allow minor changes in the full-scale output frequency, in order to compensate for variations in other components.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I set the time 10 seconds, still deosnt work. Do you mean stop time by saying simulation timebase?